# Redefine ENV variable inside a EDN file using aero

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to redefine a value of an env variable inside an EDN file in order to write some tests.

Basically, I have an EDN file (simplified here) like this:

```
{:foo #include #or [#env SOME_VAR "default.edn"]}
```

Here I am using https://github.com/juxt/aero in order to have these tag literals (`#include`, `#or` and `#env`)

Aero handles the `#env` thing using `System/getenv`, so I tried to use `with-redefs` to temporarily redefines it, but without success.

So, any tip here on how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't touch `System/getenv` at all. In which context do you need to temporarily override the value?

Comment: In some automated tests...

Comment: Perhaps run the tests in a new shell process? In bash this would be `SOME_VAR=VALUE mytest`

Comment: Stephan's option is likely best.  As an alternative, consider using the profile capabilities of aero and provide a test profile with the config settings you want.